# How to use .each() on an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. How can I print out three url address like:

```
www.example/app
www.example/map
www.example/tap
```

```js
var comp = ["app", "map", "tap"];

$(comp).each(function() {
  var url = 'www.example/' + comp;
  console.log(url);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use [`$().each`](http://api.jquery.com/each), you use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) on an array. Or, with any JavaScript engine updated since 2009, you use the array's own `forEach`.

Using `$.each`:

```
$.each(comp, function(index, entry) {
    var url = 'www.example/' + entry;
    console.log(url);
});
```

Note that the entry is the *second* argument, not the first. (It's also `this`.)

Using `forEach` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)):

```
comp.forEach(function(entry) {
    var url = 'www.example/' + entry;
    console.log(url);
});
```

Note that the entry is the first argument. (You can also use a second and third argument: The second is the index, the third is the array itself.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) has a comprehensive list of the ways you can loop through the contents of arrays and array-like things.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),

```
comp.forEach(function(url) {
  console.log('www.example/' + url);
});
```

There is no need to use jQuery `$.each()` at this context. By the way you are using `$().each`, that is different and that can be used to traverse Jquery element collection not an `array`.

Comment: You probably want to change the name of the argument, or remove the `var`. It happens that it will work as is, because the `var` will be a no-op, but...

Comment: @TJ  Anyway that would over ride it right? I did a small test in the console. `function test(url){
 var url = "helo" + url;
console.log(url)
} test("test");`

Comment: Right, that's why I said it works in this particular case, the `var` is essentially ignored.